# How to set a state in redux on page load

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

To save on code typing, my code setup is exactly [like this](https://medium.com/@notrab/getting-started-with-create-react-app-redux-react-router-redux-thunk-d6a19259f71f). Everything works fine. Now, let's say I need to pull in an initial code from my API for the `count` (state). How to do it?

```
// ./src/modules/counter.js

import axios from 'axios'

[...]

const FETCHED_COUNT = []
axios.get(<http>).then(res => FETCHED_COUNT.push(res.data))

console.log( FETCHED_COUNT[0] ) // undefined

const initialState = {
  count: FETCHED_COUNT,
  isIncrementing: false,
  isDecrementing: false
}

[...]
```

In the console log, I need my data from the api but it's nested a bit weired. It's an array so Im confused why it's undefined.

**api data fetched:**

```
{
 "counts": [
   { "id": 1, "count": 20 },
   [...]
 ]
}
```

My two cents say that this method is not used by you developers. How to set an initial state, with axios, feteched from your API? Basically, on page load, the state should be updated from an axios returned data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the api call will be made after your page loads up i.e. you must be firing the action in `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()`.

The api call is asynchronous, so `console.log( FETCHED_COUNT[0] )` is always going to be `undefined` since the axios promise will not be resolved by the time the `console.log(...)` statement is executed.

If you put console.log inside `axios(<http>).then((res) => {....// put console.log here})`, then you'll see expected response. So you need to update state AFTER the api call has returned.

For such circumstances, its best you initialize redux initial state with an empty array.

```
const initialState = {
  count: [],
  isIncrementing: false,
  isDecrementing: false
}
```

Now, after the api call, dispatch an action which would update `state.count` with the value fetched by api.

```
axios.get(<http>).then(res => {
  dispatch(UpdateCount(res.data))
})
```

Your reducers should listen to `UpdateCount` action and update the `state.count` with values fetched from api.

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly I reference `dispatch`, in which file, per link above?

Comment: See "5. Adding Redux Thunk".  So your ReactJS View should first dispatch an action -> this action should make an api call and on api call success it should dispatch an action to update reducer -> this action should update state in reducer -> state update would update the view.

Comment: Im still lost, in which file I should put that? I get dispatch in undefined when I place it in the Component file. My component file has `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  // ...
}, dispatch)`

Comment: So basically I need to import the store then `store.dispatch()` Ahhhhh could of made that care for a noob like me. Thanks. All is well!

Comment: There is also a `connect` function provided in `react-redux` package which would enable you to get `dispatch` in `props` for your component.